# Convert SQL Server Express database to SQL Server Compact database

Tags: c#, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-ce

How can I convert a SQL Server Express database to a SQL Server Compact edition database with minimum deployment by using coding?

Comment: yep.  by using coding...

Comment: @MitchWheat How it can be done?

Comment: i was using http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/03/sql-server-compact-code-snippet-of-week_8.html to convert from comapct to sql express. But now i need reverse of it.

Comment: See my new blog post here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/09/sql-server-compact-code-snippet-19.html

Comment: I think you could use NHibernate or Entity Framework to generate the schema for you.  This project may help http://nst.codeplex.com/.

Comment: @ErikEJ i am using target framework 3.5. So ExecuteSqlFile does not work. So what should i do to run sql ce script in this case.Please help.

Comment: It worked yesterday, and not today?? You could call my sqlcecmd command line tool from your app to execute the script, then

Comment: @ErikEJ no yesterday i was able to get script(script generated by code given by you)  which convert express to compact db. But then i ExecuteSqlFile was not working. How can i call sqlcecmd in code? Can i use it in my software?

Comment: Process.Start will do the trick, and you can include the sqlcecmd.exe with your app..

Comment: Process.Start will open the script file,it does not run the script file.How to run script by using sqlcecmd.exe?

Comment: Come on - Process.Start has name of .exe file as first parameter, and second parameter is command line arguments

Comment: @ErikEJ What command line need to be supplied to run the script against a database?

Comment: Look at the documentation on the Codeplex site

Comment: @ErikEJ Is this link(http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Scripting%20API%20samples&referringTitle=Documentation) you are reffering about? I didn't get the command line options

Comment: No, it is http://sqlcecmd.codeplex.com